# sumifs syntax for multiple conditions incorrect

Tags: excel, function, sumifs

I'm currently working from two worksheets, a main data sheet titled 'Equities' which details the stock trading data undertaken on a daily basis. I've attached a screenshot of the column labels below for this worksheet.

[image]

I have a monthly commission worksheet which draws information from the equities sheet using sumifs to return results to a relevant date range. I've attached the column labels screenshot below and the date column to show how it is categorised.

[image]

[image]

```
=SUMIFS(Equities!L:L,Equities!A:A,">=1/10/2018",Equities!A:A,"<=31/10/2018")
```

The above sumif returns an accurate result for the gross revenue USD column on the monthly commission worksheet. I have tried to adjust the sumif by adding an additional criteria so as to have monthly figures for Trader 1, 2, 3 etc.

```
=SUMIFS(Equities!$N:$N, Equities!$L:$L, Monthly Commission!$C1, Equities!$A:$A,">=1/10/2018",Equities!$A:$A,"<=31/10/2018"
```

The SUMIF above is the one I've edited to include the trader as an additional criteria. However, it has not worked and returns a 0 value, and also prompts me to open a file. I'm not sure where the error is in the syntax or composition of the sumif, so any advice on how to correct it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The criterion `"<=31/10/2018"` compares the cell's value to the numerical value (31/10)/2018, or 0.001536. Instead, try `"<="&DATE(2018,10,31)`.

Comment: In your first formula you are summing Equities!$L:$L. In your second formula you are summing Equities!$N:$N, and this time Equities!$L:$L has switched from being the column to sum to being one of the columns subject to a criterion (=Monthly Commission!$C1). Is this what you intended?

Comment: hi @jsheeran I have tried this but it returns #VALUE! thank you for the suggestion, do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: Hi @XORLX, and thank you so much for the assistance in my previous question. To answer, I believe column L (which has the gross comm figures) will need to be summed as it was previously. Column N which has the traders name should be a column subject to the additional criterion in C1$

Comment: So just switch the order of those two columns in the second formula you posted, as currently they are the wrong way round (the FIRST column referenced in SUMIFS is ALWAYS that to be summed - for the record, an annoyingly different syntax to that for SUMIF)

Comment: This has worked @XORLX, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because the name of the Monthly Commission sheet has a space in it, you need to put it in single quotes:

```
=SUMIFS(Equities!$N:$N, Equities!$L:$L, 'Monthly Commission'!$C1, Equities!$A:$A,">=1/10/2018",Equities!$A:$A,"<=31/10/2018")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. I've tried this and while it doesn't prompt me to open a file or give me an error, it only gives me an answer of 0. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: I've put some simple data in to test it and it works OK for me (i.e. gives a non-zero result).  Your dates look as if they are formatted OK (do they appear as 1/10/2018 etc. in the formula box?) , and I have checked @jsheeran's comment, so I don't know - sorry!

Comment: The comments from @XOR LX etc. look helpful - I think they probably explain why you are getting a zero result.

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect column was being summed, answer provided by @XORLX.

```
=SUMIFS(Equities!$L:$L, Equities!$N:$N, 'Monthly Commission'!$C1, Equities!$A:$A,">=1/10/2018",Equities!$A:$A,"<=31/10/2018")
```